# How to separate information coming from one API request

Tags: api, webservices

We have multiple objects in Salesforce. I have a use case, where user will try make an API request to create a lead in Salesforce. However, the fields/data that comes in API request has information other than lead as well, which we want to store into their respective object in Salesforce.

Is there a way we could look at an existing API request and separate the information and store it into different objects in Salesforce?

Thanks

Comment: You can. However, you should know the definition and structure of your API to extract information. Such as if you have `{"LeadInfo":{"leadName":"Lead 1",
"Lead title":"Manager"}, {"ContactInfo":{"name":"cotnact name1"}`

You can extract it with `data.contactInfo` (Data is wherever you have stored your response of API) and store it into a map of list and then access the values. Very hard to help further without the code here.

Comment: Do you have control over the API request itself? You could make a composite request, sobject Tree request, etc. There are ways to submit multiple, related or unrelated records in a single request.

Comment: You can create a custom rest API resource and handle the incoming request body as per your need.

Comment: ok so @NishantSinghPanwarlet's let's say if I am using some duplicate management tool and the data goes through it even before it hits Salesforce. Is there a way I can segregate the information, even before it hits duplicate management tool like cloudingo?